Should the direction of this close as duplicate be in the other direction, or is this perhaps a good candidate for merging?
The well-written, well-contexted and well-received recent question Formula for bump function (+20) with nine unique answers (+19, +9, +8, +8, +6, +3, +2, +1, +1) that span a wide range of solutions was closed as duplicate of a similar very short question Bump function with integral $1$ and value $1$ at zero (+3) with one simple answer (+2).
A different well-received possible duplicate Particularly nice bump function (+12) with two well-received answers (+15, +8) was ignored.
The consensus at Have there been analyses to see if views of well-received answers are reduced by closure as duplicate which try to control for other factors? is that the answer is unknowable either way, but I wonder if duplicate closures should point toward the best nexus of answers since a primary goal of SE is to produce a repository of good answers.
Question: Should the direction of this close as duplicate be in the other direction - towards the rich, diverse nexus of well-received answers - or is this perhaps one of those rare good candidates for question merging?


from FAQ: What is a "merged" question? (2012-2020)

Moderator cheat-sheet's "Merging questions" (2012-2019)

Moderator Tools - Make merging questions a little easier (2012)



The post was just reopened, and I have voted to close the less popular post as duplicate.

Personally I don't think either question should be closed as a duplicate of the other. The old one is simple and contains all needed context in  concise way, so it's probably more useful for future visitors. But the new one is a more specific problem, and the OP made it clear why the old question doesn't answer it, so it simply isn't a duplicate and shouldn't be closed as one. Closing the old question in favour of the new one would help no-one, since most of the new question's content is very specific to the OP's starting point and is unlikely to help someone with a similar problem

@N.Virgo I agree, I just though that would be too much to ask from the "question closing community" :-) Please feel free to post an answer.
